# Hibernate don't update entity after changing something directly in database?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi all I have pretty strange problem let me first show my configuration etc. Here is persitance.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="allegroTransactionPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AllegroShop?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="topSecret" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="topSecret" />
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" /> -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="/SQL/payment_type.sql"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And here is method that I use to take data from my database:

```
@PersistenceContext( unitName = "allegroTransactionPersistenceUnit", type= PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED )
protected EntityManager em;

public List<AllegroTransactionImpl> readAllegroTransactionByCreateDate()
{
    TypedQuery<AllegroTransactionImpl> query = this.em.createQuery( "SELECT allegroTransaction FROM com.springapp.mvc.classes.AllegroTransactionImpl allegroTransaction ORDER BY createDate DESC", AllegroTransactionImpl.class);
    return  query.getResultList();
}
```

And now the problem. Everything works great if I use hibernate to update / delete / add. but if I change some value directly in base (by SQL statement) hibernate don't refresh it question is why ?

Entity class

https://gist.github.com/spec8320/144100f049f54b73ad86

Comment: are you committing the changes by using commit command..??

Comment: Share your entity class.

Comment: I don't commit by commit command I make changes directly on database by phpMyAdmin panel, entity class added

Answer (score 0):

1. please make sure you had committed the change by SQL statement.
2. please check if you have enabled the 2nd level cache on AllegroTransactionImpl