# Java, spring with hibernate don't see any changes if I make them directly on DB?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi all I have strange problem. I have application fully hibernate + spring. Everything works greate if I use only hibernate to add / edit / delete object. But when I make changes directly on DB application don't see the changes? (don't update them). My persitance is pretty simple:

```
    <persistence-unit name="allegroTransactionPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AllegroShop?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="topSecret" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="topSecret" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" /> -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="/SQL/payment_type.sql"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My example class isn't very hard to undestand too:

```
@Entity(name = "PAYMENT_TYPE")
public class PaymentTypeImpl implements PaymentType {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_NAME")
    protected String paymentName;

    @Column(name = "PRICE", nullable = false)
    protected float paymentPrice;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    protected boolean active;

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPaymentName() {
        return paymentName;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPaymentName(String paymentName) {
        this.paymentName = paymentName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getActive(){
        return active;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isActive(){
        return active;
    }

    @Override
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Override
    public float getPaymentPrice() {
        return paymentPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPaymentPrice(float paymentPrice) {
        this.paymentPrice = paymentPrice;
    }
}
```

Any ideas ? Any links that can help me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate don't update entity after changing something directly in database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526050/hibernate-dont-update-entity-after-changing-something-directly-in-database)

Comment: I can't get this working at all...

Answer (score 0):

If you already have read then entities before your direct update, this is probably caused by hibernates second level cache. You can disable it with `@Cacheable(false)` annotation on your entity, which of course might affect performance.

Comment: Do you use new a EntityManager after your manual updates? Otherwise it will give you the stored entity.